# $.ajax GET on _layout.cshtml page resulting in undefined errors when posted from Controller/Action page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, get, viewmodel

I am trying to get a variable value using $.ajax as follows:

```
function ConfirmFriend(friendID, addOrDecline) {

      //Ajax Call Get All Employee Records
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          cache: false,
          url: "Home/GetLiveFriends",
          data: {},
          success: function (data) {
              var testnum = data;
              if (testnum == 0 && addOrDecline == "add") {
                  OpenBadges.issue(["https://company.blob.core.windows.net/badges/1.json"]);
              }

              var userID = '@ViewBag.UserID';

              var postData = {
                  'userID': userID,
                  'userFriendID': friendID,
                  'addOrDelete': addOrDecline
              };

              $.post('/User/Show/', postData, function (data) {
              });

              document.getElementById("HiddenPendingFriends" + friendID).style.display = 'none';

              if (addOrDecline == 'add') {
                  document.getElementById("HiddenAcceptedFriends" + friendID).style.display = 'block';
              }
              else {
                  document.getElementById("HiddenDeclinedFriends" + friendID).style.display = 'block';
              }
          },
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, error, exception) {
              alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
              alert(exception);
              alert(xhr.statusText);
              alert(textStatus.data);
              alert(error);
          }
      });
  };
```

My home controller method is as follows and calls the HomeViewModel:

```
public int GetLiveFriends()
{
  return hvm.GetLiveFriends();
}
```

And my HomeViewModel code is as follows:

```
public int GetLiveFriends()
{
  return friendRepository.Get(f => f.FriendUserID == User.UserID && f.Accepted == 1).Count();
}
```

If I call this from /Admin, /Home, /Profile etc. then it works as expected and returns the count but if i call this from /Admin/page or /Home/page or /Profile/page then I get undefined errors, what could be causing this?

Comment: Is the URL being appended to the current URL or something like that?

Comment: I solved this by changing URL to url: "/Home/GetLiveFriends"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing URL to url: "/Home/GetLiveFriends" as noted in my comments

Answer (score 0):

try this url:
 "/Home/GetLiveFriends".

"Home/GetLiveFriends" - is relative url. Target page depends from current url-address.
"/Home/GetLiveFriends" - absolute on your domen. Target address start from *domen*/*your absolute url*.